# MongoDB: Difference between $set and normal colon assignment update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I will like to know the difference between the two update operations below.

Assuming the collection doc looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "Jack",
    books: [
        {_id: "1a", title: "Book 1", rating: 5},
        {_id: "1b", title: "Book 2", rating: 3},
    ]
}
```

With [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/):

```
Customer.updateOne({_id: 1, "books._id": "1a"}, {$set: {"books.$.rating": 2}});
```

Without `$set`:

```
Customer.updateOne({_id: 1, "books._id": "1a"}, {"books.$.rating": 2});
```

When I test both, they return the same result

```
 {
    _id: 1,
    name: "Jack",
    books: [
        {_id: "1a", title: "Book 1", rating: 2},
        {_id: "1b", title: "Book 2", rating: 3},
    ]
 }
```

So, what is the difference between them? and which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose automatically adds `$set`. Check the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#update_update)

Where says:

> By default, if you don't include any update operators in update, Mongoose will wrap update in $set for you

So the result is the same because the query is the same.